# jQuery Isotope if/else issues with using indexOf

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using jQuery Isotope and trying to change HTML text in a div class, with `changeMe`, based on if/else:

```
var $chofval = $(".changeMe").html(filterAttr);

// search if it contains these strings
if ($chofval.indexOf("*") >= 0) {
    $(".changeMe").html("All Apples");
} else if ($chofval.indexOf(".green") >= 0) {
    $(".changeMe").html("Green Apples");
}
```

But it's giving `*` and `.green` on button click. Any guesses on where I am wrong?

Full code:

```
<script>
function getHashFilter() {
    // get filter=filterName
    var matches = location.hash.match( /filter=([^&]+)/i );
    var hashFilter = matches && matches[1];
    return hashFilter && decodeURIComponent( hashFilter );
}

$( function() {
    var $container = $('.isotope');

    // bind filter button click
    var $filterButtonGroup = $('.filter-button-group');
    $filterButtonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        var filterAttr = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        // set filter in hash
        location.hash = 'filter=' + encodeURIComponent( filterAttr );

        var $chofval = $(".changeMe").html(filterAttr);

        // search if it contains these strings
        if ($chofval.indexOf("*") >= 0) {
            $(".changeMe").html("All Apples");
        } else if ($chofval.indexOf(".green") >= 0) {
            $(".changeMe").html("Green Apples");
        }
    });

    // bind filter on select change
    $('.filters-select').on( 'change', function() {
        // get filter value from option value
        var filterValue = this.value;
        // use filterFn if matches value
        filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
        $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });

    var isIsotopeInit = false;

    function onHashchange() {
        var hashFilter = getHashFilter();
        if ( !hashFilter && isIsotopeInit ) {
            return;
        }
        isIsotopeInit = true;
        // filter isotope
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.offer-type',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',

            // use filterFns
            filter: filterFns[ hashFilter ] || hashFilter
        });
        // set selected class on button
        if ( hashFilter ) {
            $filterButtonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            $filterButtonGroup.find('[data-filter="' + hashFilter + '"]').addClass('is-checked');
        }
    }

    $(window).on( 'hashchange', onHashchange );

    // trigger event handler to init Isotope
    onHashchange();
});
//@ sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(filterAttr == "*") {      
    $(".Me").html("All Apples");    
}
else if(filterAttr == ".green") {
    $(".changeMe").html("Green Apples");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line changes the content of ".changeMe" with the value of filterAttr and can't retunr the value of the content of ".changeMe" object.

```
var $chofval = $(".changeMe").html(filterAttr);
```

if you like to get the content of ".changeMe" to evaluate use:

```
var $chofval = $(".changeMe").html();
```

But if you are trying to get the value of an attribute of the entitiy .changeMe defined as filterAttr use:

```
var $chofval = $(".changeMe").attr(filterAttr);
```

Or finally if filterAttr is the real value to check, use  this value in the sentence to evaluate it:

```
if(filterAttr.indexOf("*") >= 0){
    $(".changeMe").html("All Apples");  
} else if(filterAttr.indexOf(".green") >= 0){
    $(".changeMe").html("Green Apples");
}
```

See JQuery [Attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)